# Full text Indexing for Lotus Notes is slow

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

My customer have database around 2GB and set full text Indexing(server)=immediately

He has totally 12 person using that database.  During search inside the view, the latest data that they key in cant be search.

Normally only next day just allow to be search. 
I read the IBM knowledge center found that 
[Immediate] = As soon as possible after you close the database just update index.

So does it means that active user inside the database may only update after everyone logout from the system just will update the index?

If i want update directly every time user key in and allow to be search? Got anyway to force system update index within few second?

Answer (score 0):

Full text is built by the update task. Update task has a queue. You can check the averyge queue length in statistics of the server.

Use `sh stat update` for this.

Update task does also update view indizes if not told differently.

If the queue for the update task is to long, it will last long until fulltexts are up to date.

Check number of updaters by command:

`Sh config updaters`

If this returns an error, then there is only one updater. Increase the value to 2 or 4 by setting `set config updaters=2`

If you want to make sure, that view updates do not interfere with fulltext updates, then use `set config update_fulltext_thread=1` to spawn separate fulltext threads. Some of the parameters need a server restart to take effect.